# exclude files from build in electron via package.json

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am trying to build an electron app and during build creation exclude some files and folders.
I read similar topics and also bug thread on github but still cannot make it properly.

Final goal is to exclude all files with extension .py and folder named *tests* and all its subfolders.

However even simple example with one file with explicit name does not work. Can you please point me to my mistake?
Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "Build-Downloader",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "electron_main_win.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.8"
  },
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "!electron_backend.py"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the command line I use to compile my package:

```
electron-packager  ./ --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --electron-version=8.2.3  --out=electron_build --overwrite
```

Comment: check this https://www.electron.build/file-patterns

Comment: @namila007,yes, I read this and to my understanding created package.json according to it. However it is not the case, so I asked to point me to my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution on my own. I have already thrown a big stone to myself due to my stupidity :)

However I would like to share my knowledge in case somebody will need this info.

**electron-packager supports only --ignore command line arguments with RegEx**

*Note: you may use as many ignores as you want*

*Note2: do not mix names electron-packager and electron-builder, builder supports package.json :)*

So finally ultimate solution was:

```
electron-packager  ./ --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --electron-version=8.2.3  --out=electron_build --overwrite --ignore="^.*\.py" --ignore="\/node_modules" --ignore="\/tests"
```